# Did Samuel Jackson say his famous "Mother-F*****" in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

Samuel Jackson says the phrase "Mother-F*****" in lots of his movies, but I wonder if he said it in *Star Wars*.

He said it in both of *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Captain Marvel*, where both are PG-13.

Comment: Have you seriously not seen *Phantom Menace* and  *Revenge of the Sith*

Comment: I've voted to close. It's nonsensical to ask whether Samuel Jackson used a substantial swearword in a film ***aimed at children***.

Comment: He said it in both of Avengers : Infinity Wars and Captain Marvel, both are PG-13

Comment: I don't even think that phrase exists in the Star Wars galaxy; they've got their own swear words, like kr***...

Comment: @Mocas - I think you'll find that he didn't say it in either film. Or else they *wouldn't* have been PG-13

Comment: In Infinity War, he said it in the post credit scene, just before disappearing due to Thanos finger snap, and in Captain Marvel he said it I think when he got scratched by Goose the "Cat"

Comment: Maybe not fully clear/complete, but we get the intention

Comment: @Mocas Mother.... FLERKEN

Comment: @Skooba, yes, but knowing S. Jakson we know the intention

Comment: You may be thinking of “moof-milker”, a phrase that dignified and serene Jedi Master Mace Windu naturally says all the nerf-herding time.

Comment: Also, in the *Infinity War* post-credits scene, he says motherf—. We have no idea what the rest of that word was going to be. Could have been anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simply **NO**.

This list from [HuffPost in 2014](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/samuel-l-jackson-motherfucker_n_5630293) (not up to date but certainly covers the *Star Wars* prequel time frame) counts all his uses of "MF" and unsurprisingly none of the *Star Wars* films appear on the list.

<sub>Disclaimer: Profanity is not censored in quotes</sub>

> To celebrate this accomplishment we have painstakingly gathered them all into the one glorious video for your viewing pleasure. If this isn’t poetry, we don’t know what is.
>
> We wish Samuel L. Jackson another 171 motherfuckers, of health, happiness and success.
>
> “School Daze” (1988): 1 motherfucker
>
> “Jungle Fever” (1991): 7 motherfuckers
>
> “Strictly Business” (1991): 1 mother- what
>
> “Menace II Society” (1993): 5 motherfuckers
>
> “True Romance” (1993): 4 motherfuckers
>
> “Fresh” (1994): 1 motherfucker
>
> “Pulp Fiction” (1994): 26 motherfuckers
>
> “Die Hard: With a Vengeance” (1995): 7 motherfuckers
>
> “Hard Eight” (1996): 1 motherfucker
>
> “The Great White Hype” (1996): 2 motherfuckers
>
> “The Long Kiss Goodnight” (1996): 3 motherfuckers
>
> “Jackie Brown” (1997): 37 motherfuckers
>
> “The Negotiator” (1998): 2 motherfuckers
>
> “Rules of Engagement” (2000): 5 motherfuckers
>
> “Shaft” (2000): 13 motherfuckers
>
> “Formula 51” (2001): 6 motherfuckers
>
> “Basic” (2003): 2 motherfuckers
>
> “In My Country” (2004):  1 you mother- [choke move]
>
> “Freedomland” (2006): 1 motherfucker, 1 brotherfucker
>
> “Snakes on a Plane”: 3 motherfuckers
>
> “Black Snake Moan” (2006): 6 motherfuckers
>
> “Soul Men” (2008): 24 motherfuckers (2 bleeped), 2 mother-
>
> “Arena” (2011): 1 motherfucker
>
> “Meeting Evil” (2012): 1 motherfucker
>
> “Django Unchained” (2012): 4 motherfuckers
>
> “Oldboy” (2013): 8 motherfuckers
>
> “RoboCop” (2014): 1 motherfucker (bleeped)

Comment: I love how, for the most part, you can pick out the Tarantino films just by how drastically above average the MF count is.  I almost missed Django Unchained in the list because of that. ;)

Comment: You should also count Dave Chappelle's impression of him during that skit in "Chappelle's Show" - that shit cracks me up every time.